# Is there a function $f''(0)$ exists, $f'$ is not continuous on $(-\delta,\delta)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is  there a function $f\colon(-\delta,\delta)\to\Bbb R$ satisfying the folowing conditions(real number $ \delta\gt0$)?

(i) $f$ is  differentiable on $(-\delta,\delta)$;

(ii) the second derivative of $f$ exists  at $0$, that is $f''(0)$ exists

(iii) there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$, $-\delta\lt x_n\lt \delta$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$,  such that $f'$ is not continuous  at all $x_n$.

---

I can't construct such  a  example

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I thought a function has to be at least continuous to be differentiable?

Comment: @Misakov    $f'$  is differentiable at $0$,  but$f'$  is not continuous at $x_n$

Comment: @Misakov: $f'$ needs be continuous at $x=0$, nothing more.

Comment: You might be able to use something like [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function)

Comment: Such an example definitely exists. Writing one down might be a bit of a pain...

Comment: at $0$ : the Fourier series of $\{|x|\}$. it's derivative is $0$ at $0$, but at $|\epsilon| > 0$ : $f(\epsilon)= \text{sign}(\epsilon)$

Comment: @reuns No, that's not even continuous at $0$, much less twice differentiable.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich $\{ | x | \}$ is the fractionnal part of $|x|$. it is continuous  on $\mathbb{R}$, also at $0$.

Comment: @reuns The fractional part of $1/10$ is $1/10$. The fractional part of $-1/10$ is  $9/10$. It's not continuous at the origin.

Comment: the frationnal part of the absolute value $|x|$ ! not the the frationnal part of $x$ !!! then make it periodic, integrate, and you got a function corresponding to what the OP exepts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to get a function that is differentiable everywhere (with bounded derivative) but whose derivative has a discontinuity point is

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x=0 \\ x^2\sin(1/x) & x\ne 0 \end{cases} $$

Now select your $x_n$s and define

$$ f(x) = x^2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{g(x-x_k)}{2^k} $$

This places a discontinuity of $f'$ at each $x_k$, and the overall factor of $x^2$ squeezes the range of $f'$ around $0$ enough to make sure $f''(0)$ exists.

Comment: Why does $f''(0)$ exist? I'm not saying it doesn't exist. But, say, $g$ bounded and $f(x) = x^2g(x)$ does not imply that $f''(0)$ exists, so it seems that at least more explanation is needed...

Comment: Never mind - the point is your $g'$ is bounded...